# Using aggregate functions in inline scripts in elastic search queries

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to make use of the results of an aggregate function in the script_fields section of an elastic search query, however we cannot reference the aggregate result within this section of the query.  Ideally I would like to multiply the aggregations field 'MaxProductCount' by two to calculate 'ProductScore', like so:

```
{
  "filter": {
     "bool": {
       "must": [
           {
              "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "query_string": {
                        "query": "id = 6436"
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
       "MaxProductCount" : { "max" : { "script" : "doc['total'].value" } }
  },
 "script_fields" : {
       "ProductScore" : {
           "script" : "aggregations['MaxProductCount'].value * 2"
       }
   }
}
```

The error response is:

```
"reason" : {
       "type" : "script_exception",
       "reason" : "failed to run inline script [aggregations['MaxProductCount'].value] using lang [groovy]",
       "caused_by" : {
         "type" : "missing_property_exception",
         "reason" : "No such property: aggregations for class: 1b1aa6e761136e0f4c14b7223dd6639071c21bc4"
       }
```

Does anyone know whether it is possible to reference aggregation results within the script_fields section?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot embed aggregations inside a script field. A script field is a synthetic field that is created for **each document** based on some computation made on that document's field values, whereas aggregations are computed on the whole set of selected documents. So you cannot mix and match both.